# Java installed but not detected in Win10

Tags: windows-10, java

I recently installed Java 8 on my Windows 10 computer. I recently tried to run a java app and didn´t worked and now I am trying to run an installer for a java app and an error message pop ups: "Cannot find Java 1.8 or higher".

I checked the "default apps by file" in Control Panel, but there´s no application associated with .jar, .java, etc., type of files and I cannot select Java at all. I suspect it has something to do with the PATH, but I don't know how to proceed in Win10.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: What paths are contained within your current PATH system variable

Comment: %PATH%:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\MEGA-X;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Roaming\PAUP4\
In case you refer to the environmental variable path:
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\danie\AppData\Roaming\PAUP4\;

Comment: You really should have edited your question.  *C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath* is that the path to your Java 8 installation?

Comment: You are right, my bad. No that wasn´t the correct path of installation, but I don´t know why there were some java program files in Common Files and also in Program Files (x86). I tried editing the path and creating JAVA_HOME but still didn´t worked. I ended up uninstalling and installing manual mode choosing the 64 bit and this time it only installed in Program Files directory, now it works.